# How to keep token in Redux state after page reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, local-storage, redux-toolkit

so I'm using Redux-Toolkit Query on my project, and I have an authSlice, where I keep the authenticated user info and an access_token.

I also keep this info in local storage so whenever I reload the page I can get the values from the local storage and save them in the state.

The catch is that I have a RequiredAuth component that checks if the user trying to access specific routes is authenticated, by checking if there is an access_token in the state, it works fine except that if I reload this page while I'm authenticated I will be redirected to my login page.

The RequiredAuth component code:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { selectToken } from "./authSlice";


const RequireAuth = () => {
  const token = useSelector(selectToken)
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" state={{ from: 
location}} replace />
  )
}

export default RequireAuth
```

Code that gets user info and token from local storage when the page is reloaded and adds it to state:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { setCredentials, selectToken } from '../features/auth/authSlice';


const Header = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [user, setUser] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile')))
  const stateToken = useSelector(selectToken)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(user?.access_token && !stateToken) {
      dispatch(setCredentials({ user: user.user, access_token: user.access_token }))
    }
  }, [])

  // Omited code, not relevant



  return (
    <header className='nav-bar'>
      // Omited code, not relevant
    </header>
  )
}

export default Header
```

I believe whenever I reload a page where a user needs to be authenticated this happens: in the "RequiredAuth" I will get a null access_token from the state, so I get redirected and only then my useEffect will copy the local storage data to the state.

I fixed this problem by changing the RequiredAuth component to this:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const RequireAuth = () => {
  const profile = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))
  const location = useLocation()

  return (
    profile?.access_token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/auth/login" state={{ from: 
  location}} replace />
  )
}

export default RequireAuth
```

But I would like to know if there is a better way to keep data in state after reloading a page in order to solve this problem because getting it from local storage feels counterintuitive, since the data will be stored in the state after the useEffect logic completes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't keep data with a refresh. Netherless, you can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist). This package keeps the data inside the localstorage and populate automatically the store on a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I think this [redux-persist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist) package can help. It basically stores your state inside localStorage/sessionStorage and it will rehidrate your state every time you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use redux-persist with rtk for the store token. above method, if u r navigating to other routes it will work fine. suppose u r refresh the page u will redirect to the login page
Refer redux-persist

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).